# How to create an input field (HTML) that spans two lines

Tags: html, css, input

I want to be able to use an `<input>` field type of control but allow only two lines.

At the moment I am using two fields but was wondering if anyone can come up with a solution to allow input (similar to a textarea) but no more than two lines.  I control the width etc of the field.

For reference,  Jquery and Bootstrap 3 are loaded.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```js
var element = document.getElementById('tworows');

make2Lines(element);

function make2Lines(el){
  
  el.setAttribute('rows', 2); // limit height to 2 rows
  // el.setAttribute('wrap', 'off'); // ensure no softwrap is not required anymore if we limit the length
  el.addEventListener('keydown', limit); // add listener everytime a key is pressed
  
  function limit(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && this.value.indexOf('\n')>-1){
      // 13 is the ENTER key and \n is the value it make in the textarea
      // so if we already have a line break and it's the ENTER key, we prevent it
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    // async to let the dom update before changin the value
    setTimeout(limitRow.bind(this), 0);
  }
  
  function limitRow(){
    var maxLength = 10;
    var rows = this.value.split('\n');
    rows.forEach(cutOverflow)
    this.value = rows.join('\n');

    function cutOverflow(row, index, rows) {
      rows[index] = row.substring(0, maxLength);
      // this if is only if you want to automatically jump to the next line
      if (index === 0 && row.length > maxLength)
        rows[1] = row.substring(maxLength) + (rows[1] || '');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tworows"></textarea>
```

short version : `function make2Lines(a){function b(a){13==a.keyCode&&this.value.indexOf("\n")>-1&&a.preventDefault(),setTimeout(c.bind(this),0)}function c(){function c(b,c,d){d[c]=b.substring(0,a),0===c&&b.length>a&&(d[1]=b.substring(a)+(d[1]||""))}var a=10,b=this.value.split("\n");b.forEach(c),this.value=b.join("\n")}a.setAttribute("rows",2),a.addEventListener("keydown",b)}`

Comment: Great answer zeacho... Now if there was only a way to limit the number of characters to those that fit in the width of the textarea that would be awesome.... :)

Comment: I've edited the answer so you can set a max length (maxLength = 10)

Comment: Fantastic zeacho :) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways come to mind:

- You could use a `<textarea>` instead, and augment it with some script that only allows two lines.
- You could continue to use two `<input>` fields, but style them so they stack on top of each other to create the illusion of one field.  You might still need a bit of script to take care of some usability annoyances, such as pressing ENTER to go from line one to line two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about wrapping lines if the text is too long, according to documentation `<input type="text">` cannot wrap text.
However, if you are talking about limiting the character length, you could use the maxlength attribute like- `<input type="text" maxlength="10">`

Answer (score 0):

An input field can only display one line http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text. For multiline you need to use textarea and set the rows attribute. If you need two separate values you can do it after in PHP, Javascript or other means.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="2">The default text or empty for nothing this is passed as value for this field</textarea>
```